# jQuery - Immediate children

Tags: jquery, list, parent-child

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul id="mycustomid">
    <li><a>Item A</a>
        <ul class="children">
           <li><a>Child1 of A</a>
               <ul class="children">
                 <li><a>Grandchild of A</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                       <li><a>Grand Grand child of A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Item B</a></li>
    <li><a>Item C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I am using Jquery to get only the immediate children of the `ul#mycustomid`. But my code returns me with ALL the li's in my structure. How should I proceed?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var arri = $("#mycustomid>li").text();
 alert(arri);
});
```

I have tried `.children()` too, it gives me almost the same result. This is really getting on my nerves :(

My alert box outputs exactly as shown below (including those white gaps):

```
Item A 
Child1 of A
Grandchild of A

Grand Grandchild of A


ItemBItemC
```

Whereas, it should be just (without spaces):

```
Item A 
Item B
Item C
```

To understand my problem, you can check out the live version at https://jsfiddle.net/yS6ZJ/

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that your selector is working just fine - it's what you're doing with it that's got a problem.

When you call `.text()`, you get *all* the contents of the element. All of it, including the child elements.

Try this:

```
$('#mycustomid > li').each(function() {
  alert($(this).find('a:eq(0)').text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works awesome, can you please tell me *how* that logic works? I'm amazed by your intelligence (I feel like a stupid noob, ofcourse)

Comment: Just keep in mind that something like ".text()" or ".html()" applies to the complete contents of an element.  What my sample does is loop through the immediate child `<li>` elements (just like yours), and for each one it finds the **first** `<a>` tag (that's what the ":eq(0)" trick does) and grabs the content of that. Because it's *just* getting the text of that one `<a>` tag, it doesn't pick up the whole "tree" in the `<li>`

Comment: Thank you Pointy, thank you very much. You saved me loads n loads of pain and headache! By the way, just curious, how do I access the children (and grandchildren) using your logic ?

Comment: Well, from each `<li>` you could start up *another* `.find()` to do a similar search. Alternatively, you could take an entirely different approach: just find *all* the `<li>` elements, and then for each one use the jQuery `parentsUntil("#mycustomid")` to get a list of parent elements up to that root node. By the length of the list of parents, you'll be able to tell how "deep" each `<li>` is.

Comment: The jquery docs have a good concise example on this notation - notice only the outside LI tags get the border.  http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arri=$("#mycustomid > li").children('a').append('\n').text();
  alert(arri);
});
```

The `append('\n')` is there just to add a line break, so that it looks okay in the alert.

To include all grandchildren, you just remove the immediate reference to `LI`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arri=$("#mycustomid li").children('a').append('\n').text();
  alert(arri);
});
```

And to just get the grandchildren:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arri=$("#mycustomid li").not("#mycustomid > li").children('a').append('\n').text();
  alert(arri);
});
```

And to get each level, you can go for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ChildOfA=$("#mycustomid > li > ul > li > a").append('\n').text();
  var GrandchildOfA=$("#mycustomid > li > ul > li > ul > li > a").append('\n').text();
  var GrandGrandChildOfA=$("#mycustomid > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a").append('\n').text();
  alert('List of Child1 of A children:\n\n'+ChildOfA+'\n\n'+
        'List of Grandchild of A children:\n\n'+GrandchildOfA+'\n\n'+
        'List of Grand Grand child of A children:\n\n'+GrandGrandChildOfA);
});
```

Comment: Wow!Never knew it'd be soo simple :D Thanks Gert :) You rock! (and, yes, you too Pointy!!) 
Thank you all =) Peace, yo.

Comment: Gert, I don't want to 'include' the Grandchildren, instead, I want to access them or rather, display just the Grand children, just like you've done with the top level items in your first example..Can you help?

Comment: No problem. Just exclude the direct LIs. See my addition above.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work, Gert :( 
It includes the Children, Grand children and Grand,Grand children.
I just need to access a single level of elements - like either only the Grandchildren series or only the Grand Grand Children series

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EDvwj/

Comment: See above. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps this is what they refer to as "Pure Awesomeness". Thanks a million Gert, you made my day, saved me from a lot of pain. Bless you, and thanks a lot!!